# backbone fetchRelated without full=True gives only IDs and URIs

Tags: django, backbone.js, backbone-relational, tastypie

I have the following tastypie resources:

```
class ArtistResource(SearchableResource):
    audio_tracks = fields.ToManyField('music.api.AudioTrackResource', 'audio_tracks', related_name='artists', null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:        
        filtering = {
        "title": ('startswith',),
        "id": ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        }
    queryset = Artist.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'artist'
    allowed_methods = ['get']

class AudioTrackResource(SearchableResource):
    artists = fields.ToManyField('music.api.ArtistResource', 'artists', null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        filtering = {
        "artists": ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        }
    queryset = AudioTrack.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'audio_track'
    allowed_methods = ['get']
```

And the following backbone models:

```
class Track extends Backbone.RelationalModel
  urlRoot: TRACK_API
  relations: [
  {
  type: Backbone.HasMany
  key: 'artists'
  relatedModel: Artist
  collectionType: ArtistCollection
  reverseRelation:
    key: 'track'
    includeInJSON: 'title'
  }
  ]  
  Track.setup()
  Track

class Artist extends Backbone.RelationalModel
    urlRoot: ARTIST_API
    relations: [
    {
    type: Backbone.HasMany
    key: 'audio_tracks'
    relatedModel: Track
    collectionType: TrackCollection
    reverseRelation:
      key: 'artist'
      includeInJSON: 'title'
    }
    ]

   Artist.setup()
   Artist
```

And i can't set **full=True** in my Tastypie resources because it creates recursion... I don't want to set full=True at all. But i have no idea when and where to **fetchRelated()**. And it does not fetch anything because array of objects URIs is already there..
Is there any alternative way to populate many to many relationship to JSON on both sides?

P.S. i created this question after 3 days googling this problem, and i didn't find working solution.